# Concatenate js files with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const extractCommons = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'commons',
  filename: './js/commons.js'
})

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css')

const publicJS = [
  './js/bootstrap.js',
  './js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', 
  './js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js', 
  './js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js',
  './js/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min.js', 
  './js/jquery.validate/additional-methods.min.js', 
  './js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js', 
  './js/jquery.formatDateTime.js',
  './js/gpw-public.js'
];


const config = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
  devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '**': {
          target: 'http://www.gdwv2.com',
          secure: false,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      }
  },

  entry: {
    './js/theme-selector/gpw-theme-selector.min': './js/theme-selector/gpw-theme-selector.js',
    './pub/public.bundle': publicJS,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'style'),
      use: [{
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: { limit: 10000 } // Convert images < 10k to base64 strings
      }]
      }, 
      {
        // 
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'style'),
        loader: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader','sass-loader'])
      }, 
      {
        // Theme selector
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/theme-selector'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    extractCommons,
    extractCSS
  ]
}

module.exports = config
```

The `publicJS` array is a bunch of vender files. This *sort of* works. Although files are not concatenated in the order they are in the array, which generates some undefined errors. Also getting undefined variable errors in the `public.bundle.js` file from variables that are defined in scritps that are defined in scripts loaded *before* this. To be clear:

defined in myscript.js -> `var foo = "bar";`
`public.bundle.js` is loaded after `myscript.js` and tries to use `foo` but invokes a undefined variable error. Perhaps I don't understand the `webpackJsonp(...` function webpack scripts are wrapped in.

The second entry is a React app. That is working as desired.